# How to recover a user's Authenticator 2FA in AWS Cognito when MFA is set to required on the entire user pool?

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, multi-factor-authentication, aws-amplify-cli, totp

Hi all so I have asked this question over on the Amplify discord without success so hoping someone here might know more. The details of my scenario are:

- User has lost the device they had their authenticator app installed on
- User can no longer enter a 2FA code that is required during log in
- All methods that allow them (or an admin) to reset 2FA (get another setup code via setupTOTP) require an active session, which is no longer possible. Because they are prompted to enter a one time code, they cannot complete sign in.
- Because MFA is required on the pool, their personal setting cannot be disabled or reset - doing so DOES NOT reset them to MFA_SETUP, Cognito still believes they have 2FA configured (because they do, they just lost the app)
- To be clear, using AdminSetUserMFAPreference DOES NOT work - all it does is uncheck the box on their user page but MFA is still configured for them from Cognito's point of view and they are still prompted to enter a 2FA code on login
- There appear to be no admin endpoints to fix this, for example an admin equivalent of `setupTOTP`

So how can I recover this user's account, besides disabling 2FA on the entire pool, exposing the entire user base, so that one user can reset their 2FA?

What we've tried:

- Disabling the user's 2FA both in the Cognito dashboard and via the admin SDK

To be clear we do not want to enable SMS MFA and would not resolve the problem in this case anyway. We ARE willing to implement custom Cognito triggers if this would somehow solve the problem.

Comment: Sadly, there is still no way to reset MFA for specific users in a user pool that has MFA required for all.